# Http Authentication gives weird values for username/password

Tags: php, http-headers

I have the following code in PHP:

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])){
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic relam="admin"');
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    exit('You must enter a username/password to access this page.');
} else {
    echo 'Username: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Pass: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']. '<br>';
}
```

But when I enter in a username/password, sometimes it will display 'max-age=0' for the username and nothing for the password. This doesn't happen all the time and I don't know what causes it. Any ideas?

Comment: `relam`? `realm`, perhaps?

Comment: wow, my typing dyslexia never ceases to amaze. Sorry for wasting everyone's time